# SPMetal Person column generation

Tags: list, sandbox-solution, spmetal

I'm using SPMetal to generate a class for my lists to use in a Sandbox-solution (with Sandbox Visual WebParts).

However, when I generate the classes for a list column of type "Person or Group" with display value "Name with Picture", I only get the string for that person's name back (SPMetal only generates a string property for this field).

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name = "Person", Storage = "_personNameWithPicture", ReadOnly = true, FieldType = "User", IsLookupValue = true)]
public string PersonNameWithPicture
{
    get
    {
        return this._personNameWithPicture;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((value != this._personNameWithPicture))
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("PersonNameWithPicture", this._personNameWithPicture);
            this._personNameWithPicture = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("PersonNameWithPicture");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get both the person's name and the profile picture, like it does in the default list view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i'm afraid you can't get the profile picture directly.

linq to sharepoint can retrieve only id or displayname from a User field (lookup field) by set the ColumnAttribute  IsLookupValue = true or IsLookupId = true

so you can get a spuser object by the userid first, then get the profile picture.